# wxPython threads blocking

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

This is in the Phoenix fork of wxPython.

I'm trying to run a couple threads in the interests of not blocking the GUI.

Two of my threads work fine, but the other one never seem to hit its bound result function. I can tell that it's running, it just doesn't seem to properly post the event.

Here's the result function for the main calculation threads:

```
def on_status_result(self, event):
    if not self.panel.progress_bar.GetRange():
        self.panel.progress_bar.SetRange(event.data.parcel_count)
    self.panel.progress_bar.SetValue(event.data.current_parcel)
    self.panel.status_label.SetLabel(event.data.message)
```

Here's how I'm binding them:

```
from wx.lib.pubsub.core import Publisher
PUB = Publisher()
```

Here's how I'm binding the method:

```
def post_event(message, data):
    wx.CallAfter(lambda *a: Publisher().sendMessage(message, data=data))
```

And here are the threads. The first one does not work, but the second two do:

```
class PrepareThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, notify_window):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self._notify_window = notify_window
        self._want_abort = False

    def run(self):
        while not self._want_abort:
            for status in prepare_collection(DATABASE, self._previous_id, self._current_id, self._year, self._col_type,
                                             self._lock):
                post_event('prepare.running', status)
        post_event('prepare.complete', None)
        return None

    def abort(self):
        self._want_abort = True


class SetupThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, notify_window):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self._notify_window = notify_window
        self._want_abort = False

    def run(self):
        while not self._want_abort:
            do_more_stuff_with_the_database()
            return None

    def abort(self):
        self._want_abort = True


class LatestCollectionsThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, notify_window):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self._notify_window = notify_window
        self._want_abort = False

    def run(self):
        while not self._want_abort:
            do_stuff_with_my_database()
            return None

    def abort(self):
        self._want_abort = True
```

`prepare_collection` is a function that yields `Status` objects that looks like this:

```
class Status:
    def __init__(self, parcel_count, current_parcel, total, message):
        self.parcel_count = parcel_count
        self.current_parcel = current_parcel
        self.total = total
        self.message = message
```

Here's how I'm creating/starting/subscribing the PrepareThread:

```
MainForm(wx.Form):
    prepare_thread = PrepareThread(self)
    prepare_thread.start()

    self.pub = Publisher()
    self.pub.subscribe(self.on_status_result, 'prepare.running')
    self.pub.subscribe(self.on_status_result, 'prepare.complete')

    def on_status_result(self, event):
        if not self.panel.progress_bar.GetRange():
            self.panel.progress_bar.SetRange(event.data.parcel_count)
        self.panel.progress_bar.SetValue(event.data.current_parcel)
        self.panel.status_label.SetLabel(event.data.message)
```

I've tried stubbing out `prepare_collection` with `range(10)`, but I still don't ever hit the event handler.

Comment: hey morgan sorry ... i probably wont get a chance tonight to review this ... just super busy :/

Comment: @joran It's all good.

Comment: oh dang ... sorry ... I will def try and help your this weekend its just been a crazy week

Comment: @JoranBeasley No problem.

Comment: By the way - i assume you've been [here](http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks)?  Some of the code looks like that's what you're trying to adapt - is that right?

Comment: @JRichardSnape Yeah, in the process of trying to condense it, it seems I lost some important information, I'll add that back in. Yeah, that link was my starting point.

Comment: @JRichardSnape I added the call to subscribe and the event handler. Let me know if there's anything I need to add!

Comment: Cool.  my first thought is that you seem to have more than one Publisher instance which seems problematic.  It's late here now, but I'll have a proper look tomorrow.

Comment: @jrichardsnape Nope, I just have the one.

Comment: I don't think you do.  The lambda will instantiate one every time - as will `PUB = Publisher()`  at the top of the post (although I can't see where you reuse that) and `self.pub = Publisher()` in the main. However - I probs am making a mistake - it's even later here now, I should sleep

Comment: @jrichardsnape I forgot that I instantiated the global one and the one in my wx.Form in my mcve. In my application I only have the global one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be quite an involved answer and it's a little bit hard to work out exactly which of your snippets you have in each part of your code (i.e. which files they all live in).  I am assuming that you want to keep the `pubsub` method of doing this (which I think is a good idea).  If the structure of your real project is very complex, you might need more complex management of the `Publisher` than I use here - let me know...

---

Here goes - I'll put the spoiler first - here's a [one file solution](https://gist.github.com/rsnape/e7299e56eafec0e92334) for what you seem to want - a panel with a button to kick off the prepare thread, status bar and handler for when preparation has finished.  Tested with wxPython Phoenix 64 bit Python 3 and old fashioned wxPython on Python 2.7.  Both on Windows - but I can spin it up in a Linux box if necessary.

Summarising the important (non boiler-plate) bits of that file

You need a single `Publisher` object that your threads send messages to and your main thread (`MainForm` in your example I guess) subscribes to.  You could manage a `Publisher` for each thread, but I think here you only need one for the `PrepareThread`, so I'm going to go with that model for now.

At the top of your file, use

```
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub
```

This lets `pubsub` manage instantiating a single `Publisher` object.

In your thread, as you are doing, publish messages there - a slight ammendment to your `post_event` helper:

```
def post_event(message, data):
    wx.CallAfter(lambda *a: pub.sendMessage(message, data=data))
```

In your main thread - subscribe to those messages.  I'd say it's usually easiest to have one handler per message, rather than sending two different messages to the same handler as you were, so I went for

```
pub.subscribe(self.on_status_result, 'prepare.running')
pub.subscribe(self.on_status_finished, 'prepare.complete')
```

You can leave `on_status_result` as it is and define a similar `on_status_finished`.  In my example, I had this later one enabling a new button to let you do some real work.

**N.B.** You need to be careful when naming the payload of your messages - `pubsub` infers quite a bit of information about what it's expecting there and it caught me at first.

---

P.S. Right at the end of preparing this answer - I found [this blog post](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/09/04/wxpython-how-to-update-a-progress-bar-from-a-thread/).  It says something similar to what I have above, so I won't reproduce it, but they use the other method of instantiating `Publisher()` like your original example - implying that should work too. You may prefer the wording there.  Simlarly - you might find [this wxPython wiki](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Controlling%20GUI%20with%20pubsub) page useful.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need. Give me about an hour and then I'll try it out!

Comment: good job .. sorry i got busy ... in wx2.8 calls to publisher sendMessage subscribe are shared across all instances (in fact Publisher() might be returning the same instance ...)

Comment: Thanks @JoranBeasley - That's good info that I wasn't aware of - I'm not mega familiar with the pubsub framework - just used `wx` to give a few bits of code a pretty front end.  I'd give you an upvote, but I already did so when the question first came up.

Comment: no no your answer is great +1 ... my answer was actually wrong for wx3.0 so :/ (but it still helped to arrive at a working solution I think)

Comment: @joran Cool - yes - I think it did for sure.

Answer (score 4):

the problem is that the event system ends up calling the update function(event handler) from the threads themselves ,  you should pretty much never do that(basically you end up with strange race conditions and artifacts) ... always make the callback in the main thread.

wxPython has taken this into consideration and any methods called with wx.CallAfter will be called from the main program loop which is always running in the main thread.  this combined with the wx.pubsub module allow you to create your own event frame work easily ... something like this

```
def MyPostEvent(event_name,event_data):
  #just a helper that triggers the event with wx.CallAfter
  wx.CallAfter(lambda *a:Publisher().sendMessage(event_name,data=event_data))

#then to post an event

MyPostEvent("some_event.i_made_up",{"payload":True})

#then in your main thread subscribe 

def OnEventHandler(evt):
  print "EVT.data",evt.data

pub = Publisher()
pub.subscribe("some_event.i_made_up",OnEventHandler)
```

Comment: Would "some_event.i_made_up" be the same thing I pass to MyPostEvent? Also, does this work with Phoenix?

Comment: it should work on phoenix  (may need some minor modification ... but the concept in general applies)

Comment: yes that is what you would pass :P (see the examples on recieving and emitting the event )

Comment: Oops, duh. That's what I get for trying to read code after work. I'll try this out at work tomorrow and then give you the accept.

Comment: it may or may not actually resolve the issue ... but thats where I would start

Comment: I still can't get it to hit my event handler. I'm using [this](http://pubsub.sourceforge.net/usage/module_pub.html#module-pubsub.pub) which seems to be the 3.x compatible fork. I call the `MyPostEvent` inside the sub thread, right? and `pub.subscribe` from the main thread?